# How to pass multiple checkbox values into an array

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I am trying to pass values from a checkbox list when selected to a jquery function, so i can play around with the selected values. Below the code does not work

I want to be able to use the value outside of the checkbox function

So for example if i had another button outside that function it should be able to read what was stored into the array - The code below does not work for some reason, any help would be appreciated

jquery

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var vals = []
    $('input:checkbox[name="check[]"]').each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            vals.push(this.value);
        }
    });

     alert(vals[0]);
    });
    </script>
```

HTML Code

```
<form>
<input value="BOOZE" type="checkbox" name="check[]" >PUB, MATES, <br>
<input value="TV"  type="checkbox" name="check[]">BRIBING THE KIDS TO GO BED<br>
<input value="BOOZE" type="checkbox" name="check[]">RAVING TILL THE EARLY HOURS<br>
<input value="PETS"  type="checkbox" name="check[]">PLAYING GRAND THEFT AUTO <br>
<input value="GEEK"  type="checkbox" name="check[]">TWEETING ABOUT SOMETHING <br>
<input value="SPORT"  type="checkbox" name="check[]">GYM<br>
<input value="XMAS"  type="checkbox" name="check[]">SINGING CHRISTMAS SONGS<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkNumber" name="check[]">SHARING A DELIGHTFUL BOTTLE 
</form>
```

Comment: Every thing you have written is quite fine but cant understand the question clearly.

Comment: Do you expect `vals` to change when you change the values of the checkboxes?  If so, getting the values at `document.ready` is incorrect.  You should get them when you click the button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have a change handler where you need to filter the checked checkbox elements

```
 var vals = [];
 $(document).ready(function () {

     var $checkes = $('input:checkbox[name="check[]"]').change(function () {
         vals = $checkes.filter(':checked').map(function () {
             return this.value;
         }).get();

         alert(JSON.stringify(vals));
     });
 });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/arN4B/)

Comment: this is correct but here variable vals is not globel its scope is of $('input:checkbox[name="check[]"]').change(); function he can not use those values for another event or function

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method like:

```
var vals = $('input:checkbox[name="check[]"]:checked').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();

alert(vals[0]);
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uwLJD/)

Answer (score 2):

your code is correct just put

```
var vals = [];
```

outside of

```
$(document).ready();
```

like

```
<script>
var vals = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input:checkbox[name="check[]"]').each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        vals.push(this.value);
    }
});

 alert(vals[0]);
});
</script>
```